# tool to convert pre-cordinated SNOMED to post-coordinated

Tags: nlp, ctakes, snomed-ct

I have typed into the international Snomed browser tool `Superficial injury of head" to which I get the following -

http://browser.ihtsdotools.org/?perspective=full&conceptId1=283025007&edition=en-edition&release=v20170131&server=http://browser.ihtsdotools.org/api/snomed&langRefset=900000000000509007

or rather the important details:

Pre-coordinated:

```
283025007 |Superficial injury of head (disorder)|
```

*Post-coordinated:

```
82271004 |Injury of head (disorder)| + 
283024006 |Superficial injury of head and neck (disorder)| :
        { 363698007 |Finding site (attribute)| = 69536005 |Head structure (body structure)|, 
          116676008 |Associated morphology (attribute)| = 3380003 |Superficial injury (morphologic abnormality)| }
```

I would find it hard to believe that the creators of SNOMED did not have a tool to take pre-coordinated exporessions and output the post-coordinated expressions.

Any SNOMED familiars happen to know of an automated way to achieve this is a tool doesn't already exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a free online tool to do this.  But what is happening is normal form generation; in your example it is giving the definition of a pre-coordinated expression but it could be taking a post-coordinated expression and generating a different normalised expression.

Without the capability of normalising an expression it is impossible to use some more advanced features of SNOMED CT, for example inheritance testing between post-coordinated expressions requires that expressions are converted into a normal form.

Having said I'm not aware of a free tool to do this, there are explicit instructions on how to do this - if you're feeling brave: https://confluence.ihtsdotools.org/display/DOCTSG/12.3.3+Building+Long+and+Short+Normal+Forms